# Regex with 2 capture groups, "key=value" or "value_only"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to build a regex that matches either `key=value` or `value_only`, where in the `key=value` case the value may contain `=` signs. The key should go into capture group 1 and the value should go into capture group 2. Examples in R/stringr, this is the ICU engine. I have not found any combination of greedy, possessive and lazy quantifiers to get this to work. Am I missing something?

```
library(stringr)

data <- c(
  "key1=value1",
  "value_only_no_key",
  "key2=value2=containing=equal=signs"
)

# Desired outcome:
result <- matrix(c(
    "key1", "value1",
    "", "value_only_no_key",
    "key2", "value2=containing=equal=signs"
), ncol=2, byrow= TRUE)



# The non-optionality of = results in no match for #2
str_match(
  data,
  "(.*?)=(.*)"
)[,-1]

# Same here
str_match(
  data,
  "([^=]*?)=(.*)"
)[,-1]

# The optionality of =? lets the greedy capture 2 eat everything
str_match(
  data,
  "(.*?)=?(.*)"
)[,-1]

# This is better than nothing, but the value_no_key ends up in the first match
str_match(
  data,
  "([^=]*+)=?+(.*)"
)[,-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the key is before the first occurrence of the equals sign, you can use a negated character class to match all characters excluding `=`

If you don't want to match empty strings and there should be at least a single character for the value:

```
^(?:([^\s=]+)=)?(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvmk5I/1)

If the key can also contain spaces, you can exclude matching a newline instead of whitespace chars.

```
^(?:([^\r\n=]+)=)?(.+)
```

Example

```
library(stringr)

data <- c(
  "key1=value1",
  "value_only_no_key",
  "key2=value2=containing=equal=signs"
)

str_match(data,
          "^(?:([^\\s=]+)=)?(.+)"
)[,-1]
```

Output

```
     [,1]   [,2]                           
[1,] "key1" "value1"                       
[2,] NA     "value_only_no_key"            
[3,] "key2" "value2=containing=equal=signs"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a non-matching `(?:)` optional `?` group anchored to the start of the string `^`?

```
str_match(data,
          "^(?:(.*?)=)?(.*)"
          )[,-1]
     [,1]   [,2]                           
[1,] "key1" "value1"                       
[2,] NA     "value_only_no_key"            
[3,] "key2" "value2=containing=equal=signs"
```